# Friend Function C++ how to design the function that takes 2 class objects as the argument

Tags: c++, class, oop, parameters, friend

I find difficulties in this part because it takes the class objects as the parameter of the function:

```
    friend Num_Fact GCD(Num_Fact , Num_Fact);
    friend Num_Fact LCM(Num_Fact , Num_Fact);
```

How to implement the GCD function with arguments of 2 class objects, and return the value back in as Num_Fact as following in cpp:

```
    cin >> value;
    
    Num_Fact A(value);
        
    cout << "Key in number B: ";
    cin >> value;
    Num_Fact B(value);
    cout << " A = "<< A.output() <<" = "<<A.getnum()<<endl;
    cout << " B = " <<B.output() << " = " << B.getnum() << endl;
    
    Num_Fact C = GCD(A, B);
```

Original Code:

```
    #ifndef NUM_FACTOR
    #define NUM_FACTOR
    
    #include<iostream>
    #include<array>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<sstream>
    
    using namespace std;
    #define Z 20
    
    
    class Num_Fact {
        friend Num_Fact GCD(Num_Fact , Num_Fact);
        friend Num_Fact LCM(Num_Fact , Num_Fact);
        
    public:
        Num_Fact(int num) {
            Num = num;
        } 
        ~Num_Fact() {};
    
        long long int findgcd(long long int a, int b) {
            if (b == 0) return a;
            return findgcd(b, a % b);
        }
        long long int LCM2(long long int a[], int n) {
            long long int res = 1, i;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                res = res * a[i] / findgcd(res, a[i]);
            }
            fact2num(res);
            return res;
        }
        long long int GCD2(long long int arr[], int n)
        {
            long long int result = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                result = findgcd(arr[i], result);
    
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    fact2num(result);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            fact2num(result);
    
            return result;
    
        }
    
        long long int GCD(int  a, int b) {
      
            int temp;
            while (b != 0) {
                temp = b;
                b = a % b;
                a = temp;
            }
            return a;
        }
        long long int LCM(int a, int b) {
            int lcm = (a * b) / GCD(a, b);
            return lcm;
        }
    
        string Factorize() {
            ostringstream output;
            int fac = 2;
            if (Num == 1) {
                output << Num;
            }
            while (Num > 1)
            {
                if (Num % fac == 0)
                {
                    output << fac << "^"; //print the base first
                    Num /= fac;
                    int pow = 1;
                    while (Num % fac == 0) //get the power of current base
                    {
                        Num /= fac;
                        pow++;
                    }
                    output << pow; //print out the power, now we have fac^pow printed
    
                    //if not the last factor, print a multiplication symbol
                    if (Num != 1)
                        output << " * ";
                }
                else
                {
                    fac++;
                }
            }
            return output.str();
        }
    
        string output() {
            ostringstream output;
            output << Factorize();
            return output.str();
    
        }
        int getnum() {
            return Num;
        }
    private:
        int Num;
        array<array<int, Z>, 2>fact;
    };  
    #endif
```

Latest code for Header:

```
    #ifndef NUM_FACTOR
    #define NUM_FACTOR
    
    #include<iostream>
    #include<array>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<sstream>
    
    using namespace std;
    #define Z 20
    
     int findgcd(long long int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) return a;
        return findgcd(b, a % b);
    }
     int LCM2(long long int a[], int n) {
        int res = 1, i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            res = res * a[i] / findgcd(res, a[i]);
        }
    
        return res;
    }
    int GCD2(long long int arr[], int n)
    {
        int result = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            result = findgcd(arr[i], result);
    
            if (result == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    
    }
    
    int GCD1(int  a, int b) {
    
        int temp;
        while (b != 0) {
            temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
        }
        return a;
    }
    int LCM(int a, int b) {
        int lcm = (a * b) / GCD1(a, b);
        return lcm;
    }
    
    class Num_Fact {
    
    public:
        Num_Fact(int num) {
            Num = num;
        } 
        ~Num_Fact() {};
    
        string Factorize() {
            ostringstream output;
            int fac = 2;
            if (Num == 1) {
                output << Num;
            }
            while (Num > 1)
            {
                if (Num % fac == 0)
                {
                    output << fac << "^"; //print the base first
                    Num /= fac;
                    int pow = 1;
                    while (Num % fac == 0) //get the power of current base
                    {
                        Num /= fac;
                        pow++;
                    }
                    output << pow; //print out the power, now we have fac^pow printed
    
                    //if not the last factor, print a multiplication symbol
                    if (Num != 1)
                        output << " * ";
                }
                else
                {
                    fac++;
                }
            }
            return output.str();
        }
    
        string output() {
            ostringstream output;
            output << Factorize();
            return output.str();
    
        }
        int getnum() {
            return Num;
        }
    private:
        int Num;
        array<array<int, Z>, 2>fact;
    };  
    Num_Fact GCD(Num_Fact A, Num_Fact B) {
        return GCD(A.getnum(), B.getnum());
    }
    Num_Fact LCM(Num_Fact A, Num_Fact B) {
        return LCM(A.getnum(), B.getnum());
    }
    
    
    #endif
```

Latest Code for CPP

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<array>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<sstream>
    #include"Num_Factor.h"
    using namespace std;
    const int S = 20;
    void bonus();
    int main() {
        int value;
        cout << "Key in number A: ";
        cin >> value;
    
        Num_Fact A(value);
        
        cout << "Key in number B: ";
        cin >> value;
        Num_Fact B(value);
        cout << " A = "<< A.output() <<" = "<<A.getnum()<<endl;
        cout << " B = " <<B.output() << " = " << B.getnum() << endl;
    
        Num_Fact C=GCD(A, B);
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

It gives error when compiling such as "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF72E1A53DF in lab09.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000C850A03EB8)." And also its pointing at:

```
Num_Fact GCD(Num_Fact A, Num_Fact B) {
    return GCD(A.getnum(), B.getnum());
}
Num_Fact LCM(Num_Fact A, Num_Fact B) {
    return LCM(A.getnum(), B.getnum());
}
```

The task is to call the Num_Fact C= GCD(A,B), the program is about to find gcd and lcm using classes and by using constructor such as "Num_Fact"

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of confusion in your class design. but I'm only going to address some of it here. First question, ask yourself why are the `int` versions of `GCD` and `LCM` members of the `Num_Fact` class? These functions work on integers only, so there is absolutely no reason to put them in the `Num_Fact` class. So move them out of the class, it will simplify the answer to your actual question. Second question, why are these functions returning `long long int`? They have integer arguments and they can never return a value that is bigger than an `int`. So change them to return `int`, again this will simplify the answer to your actual question.

With those changes done we can talk about your actual question. As we've seen you already have functions that calculate GCD and LCM on integers, so just use those functions when you want to calculate GCD or LCM on `Num_Fact`. Like this

```
Num_Fact GCD(Num_Fact a, Num_Fact b) {
    return GCD(a.getnum(), b.getnum());
}

Num_Fact LCM(Num_Fact a, Num_Fact b) {
    return LCM(a.getnum(), b.getnum());
}
```

That's it, really simple. In fact these functions doesn't even need to be friends, since they are only using the public methods of `Num_Fact`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250334/discussion-on-answer-by-john-friend-function-c-how-to-design-the-function-that).